# Zombienet: how to build a docker image with my parachain and adder-collator binary?

Tags: docker, zombienet

In my Zombienet example network definition file, I have replaced :

```
docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master
```

with

```
docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18
```

so now my Zombienet example network definition file is the following:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/paritypr/colander:master"
  command = "adder-collator"
  
[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

Now. I need to make a docker image to replace

```
docker.io/paritypr/colander:master
```

But my new image should have adder-collator binary for adder-collator command to work.

So how can I add that adder-collator to my docker image?

That colander image is hosted here https://hub.docker.com/layers/colander/paritypr/colander/master/images/sha256-3c76e13d988aec875150e024d027af45aefc12f2de98f97db686e558a3d30513?context=explore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your collator command, which is `target/release/parachain-collator` if your parachain is based on substrate-parachain-template.
Notice there is no DOT "." before the command!

```
  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "gcr.io/x-network/collator:latest"
  command = "target/release/parachain-collator"
  args = ["--parachain-id 2000"]
```

Answer (score 2):

the `adder-collator` is very simple collator used for testing purposes and is compiled from the polkadot repo

```
cargo build --profile testnet --verbose -p test-parachain-adder-collator
```

And then *injected*  into the image using this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/scripts/ci/dockerfiles/collator_injected.Dockerfile) and published under `paritypr`.

Thanks!

Comment: Do I have to add this adder-collator to my parachain repo??? I didn't have it but I can run my parachain locally with 2 relay chain nodes... I am confused!

Comment: If I need it to run the ZombieNet test, Okay! Did you mean to run that command above in Polkadot repo, get the adder-collator binary, then copy & paste it into my parachain repo, then make a docker image for the Zombienet tests? Thanks

Comment: Hi, does your parachain repo compile a custom collator? Is this repo based on the available `template`(https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template)? Also, if you can share your repo I can check the needed config.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, mine is based on substrate parachain template